# Real elapsed time in cplex

Tags: c++, unix, cplex

I have a cplex C++ code and am trying to find the real elapsed time. I use cplex.getTime() but it returns the CPU time (I run it on UNIX system). My first question: Is the CPU time returned in seconds? That is, it says 1500. Does it mean 1500 seconds? Second question: Is there a way to obtain the real elapsed time in cplex with c++?

Answer (score 1):

cplex.getTime() should be returning the "elapsed" time in seconds, but you usually need to use the "Wall clock time" setting. The newer manuals don't make the difference very clear, but the older manuals are better in this regard. E.g. the CPLEX 10 manual says:

> The clock-type parameter determines how ILOG CPLEX measures
>   computation time. CPU time, the default, is most appropriate when only
>   one processor is used. It reports the amount of time the CPU spent
>   performing computation on behalf of your application. For parallel
>   execution, CPU time is system dependent and generally will not reflect
>   the desired metric. On some parallel systems, it may measure aggregate
>   CPU time, that is, the sum of time used by all processors. On others,
>   it may report the CPU time of only one process. In short, it may give
>   you a misleading indication of parallel speed.
>
> The alternative type, wall-clock time, is usually more appropriate for
>   parallel computing because it measures the total physical time elapsed
>   after an operation begins. When multiple processes are active, and
>   when parallel optimizers are active, wall-clock time can be much
>   different from CPU time.
>
> You can choose the type of clock setting, in the:
>
> Interactive Optimizer, with the command set clocktype i. Concert
>   Technology, with the IloCplex method setParam(ClockType, i). Callable
>   Library, with the routine CPXsetintparam(env, CPX_PARAM_CLOCKTYPE, i).
>   Replace the i with the value 1 to specify CPU time or 2 to specify
>   wall-clock time.

Alternatively just use a standard system library call to get the start and end times and do the subtraction yourself. I have done this a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, use the following code:

```
IloNum start;
start=cplex.getTime();
cplex.solve();
cplex.out() << "solution time=" << cplex.getTime()-start << endl;
```